# Solving for a variable

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, education

I have 2 equations that I want to equate to each other and solve for a certain variable in one of the equations.

```
(1/a)-(b*e^-2a)/a= -(e^-2a*V0)/a
```

I want to find a general expression for V0 where a and b are constants. Can someone give me a little nudge in the right direction? How do I tell mathematica that I want to solve for v0? I know it treats a & b as constants by default.

Comment: Note that if `e` is intended to be the exponential constant then it should be entered as `E`

Answer (score 4):

```
Solve[1/a - (b e^-2 a)/a == -(e^-2 a V0)/a, V0][[1]]
```

$$\left\{\text{V0}\to \frac{a b-e^2}{a}\right\}$$

Answer (score 1):

Another possible interpretation:

```
Solve[1/a - (b E^-(2 a))/a == -(E^(-2 a) V0)/a, V0]
```

> ```
> {{V0 -> b - E^(2 a)}}
> ```